# Guess the number, with lying allowed

Tags: algorithm

I am pretty sure you guys are aware of the Guess the Number game (there seem to be quite a few questions here already) where Alice thinks of a positive integer and Bob tries to guess it. Alice responds by either by saying "You got it", "Low", "High". The usual strategy which Bob can do, is to do a binary search which would guess the number in O(log n) guesses, where n is the number Alice was thinking about.

I have always wondered about the variant where Alice was allowed to lie.

Suppose now Alice was allowed to lie a constant number of times (known before hand both to Alice and Bob), but only was allowed to lie when responding "High", "Low" (i.e. if Bob guesses the number correctly, she has to admit that).

Is it still possible that Bob can guess the number in O(log n) guesses?

What if Bob was allowed additional queries like "How many times have you lied so far?" (which Alice has to respond truthfully)? Are O(log n) queries still possible?

EDIT: What if the number of lies was allowed to be O(logn) too, and the additional queries were: Have you lied more than x times? and Alice was allowed to lie about them...

Apologies for the EDIT.

Comment: If the number of allowed lies -- say k -- is fixed independent of n, Bob can simply ask each question 2k+1 times and will get away with O(log(n)).

Comment: Just follow every "standard" question with the "how many times have you lied" one -- and switch the answer accordingly. Result: same number of questions asked as if Alice never lied.

Comment: I love it. Two immediate thoughts (1) what about mapping the space based on probabilities (2) what would a scheme to try and identify the or incorrect answers look like?

Comment: I was not sure how many questions I can ask in question. I have edited to make the number of lies non-constant and allowed Alice to lie about how many lies... Sorry if this is off-topic (I can see a close vote).

Comment: @Jim: Yes that is interesting. Kind of like a Fault tolerant binary search :-)

Comment: Sorry folks, seems like this question might have too many variants possible and I have already edited it once. I should have put some more thought into it before posting.

Comment: What if Alice can lie multiple times with a constraint that she cannot lie two times in a row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the usual binary search algorithm. Either you get the answer, or you get an inconsistency (an empty candidate set). If you get an inconsistency, Alice must have lied at least once. Restart the binary search. Unless I'm missing something, after O(k*log(n)) steps you will get the answer (plus a lower bound on how many times she lied). You don't need to know k a priori.

Comment: I guess that was silly: once you are done, you know exactly how many times she lied. As for optimizations, in the worst (deterministic) case, I don't think you can beat k*log(n), since Alice doesn't have to lie until the very last question on any given run. If you can beat this with a randomized algorithm, I don't know; it's a good question.

Comment: I think the key is to be able to select a better starting point (than the middle) for the next round once you get a null set.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to keep it simple, turned out to be too simple :-)

Comment: @Dante: I think it's still just a lower bound, since Alice could lie twice or more before you reach an inconsistency.

Comment: For any future searchers, I found this page on math.stackexchange as well for a more in-depth solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172372/ulams-problem-guessing-a-chosen-number-in-a-set

Comment: what if Alice is not allowed to lie two times consicutively and get it in minimum search?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's still O(log n), because you specified that Alice can only lie a constant number of times. This means she can at most multiply the amount of guesses Bob makes by a constant.

Imagine that Alice can lie 5 times.
Now, no matter when alice lies, she'll end up having to contradict herself. Bob will notice this, and can start his binary search over. Alice is also restricted to lying within O(log n) guesses, or else Bob will guess the number correctly and Alice loses her chance.

So, in the worst case, where Alice lies five times, each /just before/ Bob gets the answer, she has simply caused Bob's binary search to take 6*(log n) guesses (five lies + one correct answer), which is still O(log n).